# Programmatically setting http request headers in javascript for Content-Type

Tags: javascript, post, content-type

I'm writing some code to handle sending post data for my application and I wanted to make it so that I can send custom headers from another function if I need them.  My question is, can I default something like "Content-Type" the way my code example does below and then overwrite it, or do I need to check the custom headers being sent, and if Content-type is not set, set it to the default. Basically, during the creation of the post request, can you overwrite headers programmatically?

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", formData.length);    
// check for custom headers
if ((headers !== null) && (headers !== undefined)) {
    for(var k in headers) {
        if(headers.hasOwnProperty(k) {
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(k.toString(), headers[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sending a different "Content-Type" like JSON perhaps in the "headers" object. If I do setRequestHeader on Content-Type again does it overwrite or does it send 2 content-type headers in the post request?

*edit*: I don't know why I asked this on StackOverflow, I just realized I could probably test this by logging my headers with a form handler, which I'm off to do, I'll leave the question up anyway.

Comment: Be careful with `for..in` loops and not using `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @AlexW I'm really not clean on what that does still even after reading about it, but I added to my loop.

Comment: It prevents unnecessary iterations over properties in an object's prototype chain. Most of the time you don't want to iterate over the prototype properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader()):

> Sets the value of an HTTP request header. You must call
>   setRequestHeader()after open(), but before send(). If this method is
>   called several times with the same header, the values are merged into
>   one single request header.

So calling `setRequestHeader()` multiple times will yield the following:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json
```

Comment: Yes, I just tested this like I put in my question with a curl request and a php script to log headers.. it does exactly that.  My assumptions were double wrong, it neither overwrites or sends two but merges. So I guess if I want default headers in my function I need to check the headers being sent first.